# BCILAB MATLAB error 'too many input arguments'

Tags: matlab, input, arguments, cd

I am trying to get BCILAB on MATLAB. When I try to access the downloaded file, I get an error. My command prompt and  error received are below:

```
cd C:\Users\sara susu\Documents\MATLAB/BCILAB-1.1/;startup
```

> Error using `cd`
>   Too many input arguments.

Answer (score 4):

put your folder path inside of Apostrophe ( '...' ) like this:

```
cd C:'\Users\sara susu\Documents\MATLAB/BCILAB-1.1/'
```

you can take a look at :[here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) for detail.